# How to get and populate Zero '0' if no record found in SSRS Report 2005

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am using SSRS report to get the result based on the category and the category value changed to Yes,No,Not Met by replacing with 1 = Yes, 2 = No, 3 = Not Met.
The query is,

```
SELECT (
    CASE
        WHEN    A = '99' or B = '99'    THEN 3
        WHEN    C + D >= 10 THEN 1
        ELSE 2
    END) as Category,
```

and the result is,

```
             N     %     N    %    N     % 
Not Met      10    11%   5    7%   45    20% 
Yes          4     5%    30   4%   8     6%
No           10    11%   5    7%   45    20%
```

and if for example no result found for "Not Met", i want result like this with Zeros instead.

```
             N     %     N    %    N     % 
Not Met      0     0%    0    0%   0     0% 
Yes          4     5%    30   4%   8     6%
No           10    11%   5    7%   45    20%
```

I have tried Left Join in the query but it will bring extra record. i am kind of stuck and don't know how to get Zero '0' result if no record found for Yes, No or Not Met.
My query is,

```
SELECT (
    CASE
        WHEN    A = '99' or B = '99'    THEN 3
        WHEN    C + D >= 10 THEN 1
        ELSE 2
        END
       ) as Category, [Table A].*, [Table B].*
       FROM Table A inner join Table B on Table A.id = Table B.id
       WHERE
        (
            Condition and Field is not null
        )
```

Please help as this is my final project and i am stuck.

Thanks.

## MY SAMPLE DATA...

```
MY SAMPLE DATA

TABLE A
=======  

ID -------REFNO-------BGDATE-------SBRST-------xx   xx ...
--      ---------   --  --          
1209-------23-------09/09/1900-------13-------XX    XX
3453-------12-------14/02/1978-------10-------XX    XX
3476-------56-------02/03/1980-------10 -------XX   XX


TABLE B
=======

ID-------- CITY  -------xx  xx ...    xx
--      --      --  --
1209-------Glasgow-------xx-------X
3453-------Edinburgh-----xx-------X
3476-------Manchester----xx-------X
```

---

```
SELECT
(
CASE
    WHEN BGDATE = '09/09/1900' THEN 3

    --I tried this to get Value 3, if no condition met but no success 
    WHEN NOT EXISTS(BGDATE = '09/09/1900') THEN 3

    WHEN SBRST IN ('11','12') THEN 1
    ELSE 2
    END
) as Category, [Table - A].*, [Table - B].*
 FROM [Table - A] inner join [Table - A] on [Table - A].id = [Table - A].ID

 ----> For Ian <-----This is sample data of my WHERE clause
    WHERE
(   
        (
            SBRST IN ('4','5','6','7','11','12') AND SBRST<>'99
            AND NOT
                (
                    EXTNT IN ('2','3','4','99') OR 
                    HOR IN ('2','99') OR
                    (DATEDIFF(day,CHDATE1,CHENDATE1)>='42')
                )
        )
        AND
        (
            SBRST IS NOT NULL AND
            EXTNT IS NOT NULL AND
            HOR IS NOT NULL
        )
)

order by Category desc
```

---

```
RESULT
======
category----------ID----------REFNO----------BGDATE----------SBRST----------xx
3-----------------1209----------23----------09/09/1900----------13----------XX
2-----------------3453----------12----------14/02/1978----------10----------XX
2-----------------3476----------56----------02/03/1980----------10----------Xx
```

Points to be considered:

1) The above is my sample data.

2) Table A and B has inner joins on ID will bring the results.

3) Populating the Category based on the above SELECT condition, but the problem is, *if there is no condition matching, no category gets populated but i want the missing category as well. In this case it is "1".

I want some thing like this.

```
EXPECTED RESULT
======
category----------ID----------REFNO----------BGDATE----------SBRST----------xx
3-----------------1209----------23----------09/09/1900----------13----------XX
2-----------------3453----------12----------14/02/1978----------10----------XX
2-----------------3476----------56----------02/03/1980----------10----------XX
1-----------------0-------------0-----------NULL----------------0-----------NULL
```

Another solution could be, if i create another table with all the 3 categories in it and then use RIGHT OUTER JOIN to get the results but i do not know HOW??

Comment: Can you post raw data from Table A and Table B?

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue once. I did a quick fix by creating a temp table and inserting the results into the temp table and then checked to see if any of the three categories were missing from the temp table then inserted a row into the temp table with the desired default values in there. Below is an example code (just to give you an idea)

```
SELECT (
    CASE
        WHEN    A = '99' or B = '99'    THEN 3
        WHEN    C + D >= 10 THEN 1
        ELSE 2
        END
       ) as Category, [Table A].*
       INTO #Temp
       FROM [Table A]

IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #Temp WHERE Category=1)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #Temp (Category,column1,column2,column3,etc...) VALUES ( 1,0,0,0,etc...
    )
END
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #Temp WHERE Category=2)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #Temp (Category,column1,column2,column3,etc...) VALUES ( 2,0,0,0,etc...
    )
END
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #Temp WHERE Category=3)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO #Temp (Category,column1,column2,column3,etc...) VALUES ( 3,0,0,0,etc...
    )
END

SELECT * FROM #Temp 

DROP TABLE #temp
```

Comment: Thanks Kamran for your reply,

Comment: Kamran Thanks for your reply..I liked your idea, but could you please explain a bit more of how to Create table on the the fly because fields will be different for every report and there will be only 2 table involved (1 is main table and 2nd contain permission according to user role).
Secondly my user has only browse/view permission, will it be possible for them to create table because report has security factor too.
Please tell me where to add CREATE and DROP command.

Comment: Hi Azy, you can handle the column names dynamically so that the columns grow according to the table definition. you can find the column names via sys.tables with something like this:
SELECT a.collation_name FROM sys.columns a WHERE a.object_id=OBJECT_NAME('enter table name here').
As you will be using SELECT INTO command you do not use a create statement and the DROP should be after your desired result is returned. I hope this helps

Comment: Hi Kamran, I am half way through, i am getting result if i implement the idea on one table i.e. Table A, but i have another table i.e. Table B. Table B has some fields which are same as of Table A. Also result is coming by INNER JOIN from Table B. Please give suggestion how to join your above idea with Table B. (For more detail see my first posted question.) Thanks so much.

Comment: When i insert INTO #Temp, the result of Table A, Table B then i get the following error, since Table B has 2 fields same as of Table A fields.                                                                    Error:  Msg 2705, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
Column names in each table must be unique. Column name 'ID' in table '#Temp' is specified more than once.

Comment: you can get around that by assigning alias to the columns. e.g: ID AS Table_A_ID

Comment: Kamran, thanks for your reply. I think we are nearly there, last thing i am having issue with is that, the query run fine in SQL Management studio but SSRS report gives error as "Invalid object name #temp"??

Comment: how are you referencing the results. Are you using a stored procedure or a query?

Comment: I am using one query for all work. 1. Select Query (Select with Category and inserting in '#Temp' before FROM and Where) 2. Checking of Category-value, Inserting values for missing Category. then finally 3. Selecting the result from #Temp Table and then dropping the table. But i am getting error in this line.. IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM #Temp WHERE Category=1) and so on.. Do we need to use SProcedure, if Yes then how?

Comment: Can i have your email address so that i can send you my query, thanks

Comment: Query. No stored procedure. Does it make any difference?

Comment: I have managed to give ALIAS to the second table, so that is sorted but i am keep getting Error: Invalid object name on "#Temp".

Comment: Hi Kamran..Could you please help

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query something like this:

```
select cat.Category
  , a.ID
  , b.CITY
  , a.BGDATE
  , a.REFNO
  , a.SBRST
from
  (
    select Category = 1
    union all
    select Category = 2
    union all
    select Category = 3
  ) cat
  left join
  (
    [Table - A] a
      inner join [Table - B] b on a.ID = b.ID
      cross apply
      (
        SELECT Category = CASE WHEN a.BGDATE = '09/09/1900' THEN 3
          WHEN a.SBRST IN ('11','12') THEN 1
          ELSE 2
          END
      ) c
  ) on c.Category = cat.Category
order by Category desc
```

I've created a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/52a1b/1) which shows this gives the required results.

The key point to note is that I am using a subquery to create the required categories (the `cat` subquery), then using a `left join` to join this to the actual results - this makes sure all required categories are always included.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am going to try with my query and actual data and let you know very soon.

Comment: Hi Ian, thanks for your brilliant idea. After applying the query on the real data, i am getting all the category i.e. 1,2,3 but with all extra records. So i added the WHERE condition which is the part of actual query and now i am getting again only the true condition categories. thats mean again no missing category is coming.I have added the WHERE condition just before "order by Category desc" command. i would really appreciate if you solve this mystery for me. Thanks

Comment: Please see my WHERE Clause in upper original query with your name in comments.